# Stochastic process with right-continuous paths, intersection of borel preimages

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X=(X_t)_{t\in \mathbb{R^+}}$ be a stochastic process with right continuous paths adapted to the filtration $\mathbb F=(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in \mathbb{R^+}}$ and assume $B$ is a Borel set.

I have stumbled upon these ideas and I am not sure to what extent they are valid and whether one implies the other:

1. Is it correct to assume, based on right-continuity, that $${\{X_s \in B\}}= \bigcap_{\varepsilon>0}{\{X_{s+\varepsilon} \in B\}} $$ 
   and, if so, how can it be shown rigorously?
2. This second one I have seen many a times in slightly different forms:
   $${\bigcap_{s  \in I} \{X_s \in B\}}= \bigcap_{s \in\mathbb{Q} \cap I}{\{X_{s} \in B\}}$$ where $I$ is, say, an interval. I understand that it has to do with the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ but could someone show it in detail? Does right-continuity matter at all? What about 
   $${\bigcup_{s  \in I} \{X_s \in B\}}= \bigcup_{s \in\mathbb{Q} \cap I}{\{X_{s} \in B\}}$$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $\{X_s \in B\} = \bigcap_{\epsilon>0} \{X_{s+\epsilon} \in B\}$

This identity does, in general, not hold true; even for very nice sets $B$. Note that this would mean that $X_s(\omega) \in B$ for some $s \geq 0$ implies $X_{s+\epsilon}(\omega) \in B$ for all $\epsilon >0$, i.e. after hitting the set $B$ the path will stay in $B$.

Counterexample: Consider the deterministic process $X_t := t$ and $B:=\{0\}$. Then $\{X_0 \in B\} = \Omega$, but $\{X_{\epsilon} \in B\} = \emptyset$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

> $\bigcup_{s \in I} \{X_s \in B\} = \bigcup_{s \in \mathbb{Q} \cap I} \{X_s \in B\}$

Whether such an identity holds depends where much on the set $B$. For general Borel sets $B$ this does, in general, not hold true.

Example: Consider again $X_t := t$. If we define $B := \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$, then $$\bigcup_{s \in \mathbb{Q} \cap I} \{X_s \in B\} = \emptyset$$ for any interval $I$. However, $\{X_s \in B\} = \Omega$ for $s \geq 0$, $s \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$, and therefore $$\bigcup_{s \in I} \{X_s \in B\} = \Omega.$$

From now on, I'll assume for simplicity that $I=[0,\infty)$; for the more general setting see the remark at the end of my answer.

The identity **does** hold true for open sets $B$. The inclusion "$\supseteq$" is trivial; to prove "$\subseteq$" we have to use the right-continuity. If $X_s(\omega) \in B$ for some $s \in I$, then we can choose $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(X_s(\omega),\epsilon) \subseteq B$ for all $\epsilon>0$. Now the right-continuity implies that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$|X_s(\omega)-X_t(\omega)| < \epsilon \qquad \text{for all $t \in [s,s+\delta]$}$$ and therefore $X_t(\omega) \in B(X_s(\omega),\epsilon) \subseteq B$ for $t \in [s,s+\delta]$.

> $\bigcap_{s \in I} \{X_s \in B\} = \bigcap_{s \in \mathbb{Q} \cap I} \{X_s \in B\}$.

This holds, for instance, if $B$ is closed and $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is right-continuous. The inclusion "$\subseteq$" is obvious. To prove "$\supseteq$" suppose that $X_s(\omega) \in B$ for all $s \in \mathbb{Q} \cap I$. Now for $t \in I$ choose a sequence $s_n \in \mathbb{Q} \cap I$ such that $s_n \downarrow t$. Then, by the right-continuity,

$$X_t(\omega) = \lim_{n \to \infty} X_{s_n}(\omega).$$

Since $X_{s_n}(\omega) \in B$ it follows from the closedness of $B$ that $X_t(\omega) \in B$.

If $B$ is not closed, then we can, in general, not expect that such an identity holds.

**Remark:** In the proofs we have used that for any irrational $s \in I$ there exists a sequence $s_n \downarrow s$, $s_n \in \mathbb{Q} \cap I$. Therefore, the statements remain valid if we replace $I=[0,\infty)$ by one of the following sets:

- $[a,b)$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $b \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$,
- $(a,b)$ for $a \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty\}$, $b \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$,
- $[a,q]$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $q \in \mathbb{Q}$
- $(a,q]$ for $a \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty\}$, $q \in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Why does it follow from  $X_t(\omega) \in B$ for $t \in [s,s+\delta]$ that $X_t(\omega) \in B$ for all $t \in I$?

Comment: However your reasoning helped me obtain the following result for the union. Let $I$ be an open interval and $B$ an open set, then $$\bigcup_{s \in I} \{X_s \in B\} = \bigcup_{s \in \mathbb{Q} \cap I} \{X_s \in B\}$$

Now,  The inclusion "$\supseteq$" is trivial and for "$\subseteq$" follow your reasoning. We get  $X_t(\omega) \in B(X_s(\omega),\epsilon) \subseteq B$ for $t \in [s,s+\delta]$. And since $\delta$ can be chosen such that $[s,s+\delta] \subseteq I$ then also for some rational number $q \in[s,s+\delta]$ $X_q(\omega) \in B$. Do you think this can be extended to other $I$?

Comment: @Holden94 I'm sorry, I must have been still half asleep when I wrote the answer this morning. Actually, I confused the second and the third part of my answer. Sorry about that; should be fine now.

Comment: In case of union, I still think we need to put some restriction on $I$. E.g. in the case when $I$ is an interval of any of the forms $(a,b), [a,b), (-\infty,\infty), (-\infty,a), (-\infty,a),  [a,\infty)$ then the arguments are valid. However, assume $I=(1,\sqrt{2}]$. Then in the case when for some $\omega_0$ $\sqrt2$ is the only index such that $X_t(\omega_0) \in B$, then right-continuity won't be of much help.

Comment: @Holden94 you are right about that.

Comment: Could you please edit that part in the answer? So that I can accept it. And thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @Holden94 Done....